# Can't import xml file to wordpress on xampp

Tags: xml, wordpress, import, xampp

Precisely as the title says, I can't import the XML file onto my Wordpress site that I have installed on Xampp. I get the following error message:

"*Warning: POST Content-Length of 20021976 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0*" which originates a weird second error message displayed below the first error message: "File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini."

The file is not empty, I have opened it on Dreamweaver and there is plenty of information. I tried to google about this but could not find any other person who has had the same issue as me. (strange)

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

After a more creative search I found out that I should be changing the value of the "post max size" on the php.ini, which I did:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=25M
```

Problem? I still get an error:

"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini."

So, what can be the issue?